# How to filter datagriview using ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, filter, combobox

I have a dataGridView contains student information (class, gender, date of birth, parents name, etc.) The datagridview was bind to sql server object datasource. I want to add combobox above the datagridview to filter the datagridview based on students class, so when user select a certain class (for example class IIA) the datagridview only shows students from class IIA. 
here is my code:

```
 private void frmdbSiswa_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db = new SiswaSMSEntities();
        tabelSiswaBindingSource.DataSource = db.Tabel_Siswa.ToList();
        kelasBindingSource.DataSource = db.Kelas.ToList();
        jenisKelaminBindingSource.DataSource = db.Jenis_Kelamin.ToList();
        agamaSiswaBindingSource.DataSource = db.Agama_Siswa.ToList();
        dataGridViewSiswa.DataSource = db.Tabel_Siswa.ToList();//agardataselalutampil
        cboKelas.DataSource = db.Kelas.ToList();
        count();
    }
```

and here is the code to search the data:

```
enter code he  private void txtCariNama_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridViewSiswa.DataSource = db.Tabel_Siswa.Where(x => x.NamaSiswa.Contains(txtCariNama.Text)).ToList();

    }
```

This code works. I can search students quickly just by typing their name.

and here is the code to filter the datagridview:

```
private void cboKelas_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridViewSiswa.DataSource = db.Tabel_Siswa.Where(x => x.IdKelas == cboKelas.SelectedIndex).ToList();
    }
```

this code does works, but the problem is when I select class IA (Id 1) datagridview shows nothing, and when I select class IB(Id 2) the datagridview shows students from class IA. the datagridview shows nothing when I selected the first class [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/balNv.png). the datagridview shows students from first class when I selected the second class[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHJ96.png).
So anyone knows what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So what about using Stored procedure to do this process just create stored procedure and and build your query to to execute as a parameter contain the name of group that you put it on Combo Box , then write a lot of if conditions inside the event of Combo Box SelectedIndexChanged . finally check the group name and send it to your stored procedure as a parameter the store   ...

// 1 - Create stored procedure

```
Create proc CheckClass 
 @ClassID 
 as
 Select * from TableName 
 where ClassID = @ClassID`
```

The First ClassID Belong to the field in your table  and the second one is the parameter so it's simply stored procedure not contain more informations . 
if you have got a Data Access Layer just you build your class for check and put your if conditions .